# Admob bannerview loadrequest call cause game flickers or jerk

Tags: admob, unity-game-engine

I want to monetize my new game with two of the best ad networks AdMob and Chartboost as effectively as possible. I had problems earlier with delays and stuffs like that while showing interstitial. To avoid this, I preloaded admob and cached cb interstitials before attempting to show. It worked to some extent and I can see the improvement.

**But the problem is with the AdMob banner. As I already mentioned in my previous question, since I destroy and create bannerview everytime I move on to game play screen, I can see my game flickers for a moment. This is because of the fact that banner view LoadRequest() trigger.**

Calling Admob LoadRequest in another thread solve this ?

If so, how to trigger Admob bannerview loadrequest in separate thread in unity5?

**Update:**

```
// Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
     BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
     // Create an empty ad request.
     AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
     // Load the banner with the request.
     bannerView.LoadAd(request);
```

Comment: Could you please post your code snippet ?

Comment: Arun, I edited my post. added code snippet for bannerview creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better you put this implementation in StartCoroutine(). For example,

```
StartCoroutine(createBannerView());

IEnumerator createBannerView() {
   yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); 
// Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
     BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
     // Create an empty ad request.
     AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
     // Load the banner with the request.
     bannerView.LoadAd(request);

}
```

To solve your flickering problem, make sure you call this method before you move on to the game play area. I don't think LoadRequest causing any flickering stuff, cos these network calls generally happens in the background and wouldn't interrupt Update() or FixedUpdate().